# Rails 3 - SimpleForm - How can I get the HTML input name that would get assigned when calling form.input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I'm using SimpleForm with Rails 3, I have several nested simple_fields_for, it's a pretty complex form.

If at some point in the form I call:

```
 form.input :notes
```

I get something like this:

```
 <input name="job[shifts][shift_id][notes]" />
```

Is these something I can call that will return that Field name?

Something like:

```
 form.whatever :notes   # Returns "job[shifts][shift_id][notes]"
```

Thanks!
Daniel

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the field name?

Comment: Pass it on to a jQuery plugin that unfortunately refuses to use an input I generate on the server, and instead wants to create its OWN hidden field. I could modify the plugin, but if I can use it as it is, I'd rather just tell it what to call the field, so that it's there where I need it in the Postback.

Answer (score 1):

Wrote this helper to do it after debugging FormHelper like crazy

```
def dom_input_name(form, field_name)
  "#{form.object_name}[#{field_name.to_s.sub(/\?$/,"")}]"
end
```

Called like:

```
dom_input_name(form, :notes)
```

Hope it helps someone